# Why is does inheritance order or mapping affect the subscript of the vftable? (for the VSC for C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, polymorphism

When playing a little bit around with polymorphism, I've tried to do something like the following:

```
class a { virtual void method() { } };
class b { virtual void method() { } };
class c : public a, b {
    virtual void method() { }
    virtual void anotherMethod() { } // (1)
};
class d : public c, a, b // (2)
{ virtual void method() { } }; // C2369
```

At my knowledge this should work without any problem. But the compiler tells: 
`error C2369: 'const d::'vftable'{for 'a'}' : redefinition; different subscripts` 
And I have no idea why this is happening. There are three ways to solve that error: Either  the method `(1)` could be removed or the inheritance order `(2)` could be changed. 
**Edit:** And also applying virtual inheritance could solve it. So it seems as if the inheritance order or mapping affects the `vftable`. The `vftable` is an array for virtual member function mappings - aka. dynamic binding in C++.

Therfore I've also looked at [microsofts documentation towards C2369](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5datzk5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) where they show this as an example, how to reproduce that error:

```
int a[10];
int a[20];   // C2369
int b[20];   // OK
```

In other words changing the inheritance order changes the subscript of this table?! Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly `virtual` inheritance? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance

Comment: Yes this also seems to solve that problem, I will add it to my question. But I still do not understand why it affects the subscript of the `vftable`.

Answer (score 0):

Classes inherit privately by default (opposed to structs)! Therefore "c" only inherits publicly from "a"! You're missing another public-keyword there:

```
class c : public a, public b
```

Another problem you're facing is that you're inheriting from 2 classes that define the same member-function. a::method does not map to the same address as b::method! Your next problem will likely be, that calls to "method" are ambiguous...

Comment: Yes of course that was the case I wanted to check while playing around. And yes you are right the address of `a::method` doesn't map to `b::method`. But shouldn't the compiler be able to solve that?
BTW: Adding the public modfiers doesn't change anything in my eyes.

Comment: You only end up with one `void method()` in `d`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545897/multiple-inheritance-with-clashing-methods (although it quotes the old standard).

Comment: He can't resolve it 'cause these two member functions aren't necessarily the same! If the compiler did that it would break the idea of multiple inheritance on a fundamental level...

Comment: Thats what I've expected this example should do/show. And exactly this is the problem I think. The `vftable` should contain this one method because both declarations are overridden/hidden(?) in `class d` + the additional method (2) of `class c`.